# Speed up JOIN with subquery

Tags: mysql

In a wordpress database, I want to select all published articles from authors who have written at least five articles, and replace the authors' IDs with their login names. I accomplished that with a selection of all published posts, filtering that two times with a `JOIN` statement, one of them joining the result set of a subquery to get those authors with more than five articles.

Here we go with the code:

```
SELECT posts.post_author, users.user_login, posts.post_content, posts.post_date
FROM zwzt_wp.zwzt_wp_posts AS posts 

INNER JOIN zwzt_wp.zwzt_wp_users AS users
ON posts.post_author=users.id

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT posts1.post_author, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM zwzt_wp.zwzt_wp_posts AS posts1 
    WHERE posts1.post_type='post' AND posts1.post_status='publish'
    GROUP BY posts1.post_author
    HAVING count > 5
    ORDER BY posts1.post_author
) as regular_users
ON posts.post_author=regular_users.post_author

WHERE posts.post_type='post' AND posts.post_status='publish'
ORDER BY posts.post_author, posts.post_date DESC;
```

To me this looks kinda bloated and time intensive to run, especially since I run two select queries on `posts`. Is there any way to accomplish this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do to simplify the query.  But, there are some things you can do:

- Remove the `ORDER BY` from the subquery.
- Create an index on `zwzt_wp_posts(post_type, post_status, post_author)`.
- Make sure you have indexes on `users(id)`.
- Make sure you have an index on `zwzt_wp_posts(post_author)` as well.

If this type of information is regularly used in queries, you might want to set up triggers to maintain the counts at the user level.